# Notation for the class of all cardinals

Tags: notation, set-theory, cardinals

I have seen the notation for the class of all ordinals to be $\rm Ord$ or $\rm On$, is there an analogous notation for the class of all cardinals?

Comment: You can try to search for some reasonable phrase in [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?q=denotes+%22the+class+of+all+cardinals%22) (or perhaps Google Scholar or just Google) to see what various authors are using. (I also tried to restrict subject to [set theory](http://books.google.com/books?q=denotes+%22the+class+of+all+cardinals%22+subject:%22Mathematics+/+Set+Theory%22). But this does not seem to work too well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing particular standard, but $\rm Card$ has been used before, I have seen $\Gamma(M)$ denoting the cardinals of a model $M$, although more in the context of failure of choice where this is a partial order.

Cantor originally used Tav (ת) the last letter of the Hebrew alphabet to denote the class of cardinals. But that didn't stick.

Comment: I always use $\mathrm{Card}.$ Good to give one's functions explicit domains and codomains, ya know?

Comment: No, I don't. I often find it much much easier to just define the function and have the reading deduce the obvious domain and codomain, especially when their definitions can be cumbersome, but immediate from the definition of the function.

Comment: I think we'll have to agree to disagree on this one. Maybe I'll comment with my thoughts on the issue if I can sort them out.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's always better. But once you reach a sufficient level of complexity in describing something (that you don't want to introduce a term for a single use), it can be easier to just define a function, show it's well-defined (if you really have to do that, usually that comes for free) and get it over with. Especially since in set theory we are not bounded by domain or codomain to define a function.